# Getting PyScripter to recognize Python installed with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, 64bit, pyscripter

I am trying to get PyScripter 3.3 64-bit to run on my desktop computer.  I was successful in getting PyScripter 32-bit to run, but I require the 64-bit version.

It seems that it is unable to recognize the Python (3.6.2) engine that was installed with ArcGIS Pro 2.1, when I attempt to launch PyScripter I receive the following error:

[image: Error Message]

What steps should I take to get PyScripter to recognize my installed version of Python?

*Note: I also currently have ArcGIS Desktop software installed on my computer with its version of Python (2.7.14).

Comment: I gave up trying to use pyscripter for scripts that will run in Pro. Go to the  package install in the options and install another IDE called spyder. When that is installed it works with python 3 and the version of arcpy for pro. I can just run it about another colleague has to go to the python command line window in the ArcGIS group on windows and run it from there, not sure why...

Comment: +1 for spyder. And for a full featured IDE that works with Desktop and Pro (and conda and virtualenv) python, I recommend PyCharm, though it has a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a lot of research and determined that Pyscripter does not work well with virtual environments; therefore it does not work well with ArcGIS Pro 2.1; and I was unable to get them to connect.

I attempted to install Sypder from the Python Packages provided with ArcGIS Pro 2.1, but unfortunately I could not get them to work either; as the install kept failing.  I contacted Esri regarding this issue and they stated that 'this problem can occur when the Python Package Manager doesn't have permissions to folders, or network access to reach the modules stored in Conda'.  Then they suggested that I run `conda install -c anaconda spyder` in the Python Command Prompt, and it worked to install the package as long as I was running the Python Command Prompt as an Administrator.  This successfully installed the Spyder package.

So I installed PyCharm Community Edition (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows); and everything seems to work properly now.  For the setup I followed the steps in the initial post at the following link (https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-8359) and I am now able to work with the correct version of python.

Answer (score 2):

I have ArcGIS Pro 2.3.1 installed along with Pyscripter 3.4.2 64bit.
Running Anaconda Python 3.6.6 64bit (managed by ArcGIS Pro)

stock Python location, read-only
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3

From the Pro Python Package Manager, I've Cloned and Activated Python to a new env.
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone

the ever important ArcGIS PTH file is present,
arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\ArcGISPro.pth

to add the venv to Pyscripter,
Run, Python version, Setup Python, +, path to the conda env folder (arcgispro-py3-clone in my case)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

PyScripter, at least recent versions, work fine with ArcGIS Pro and conda environments. See the blog post on [Using PyScripter with ArcGIS Pro](https://pyscripter.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-pyscripter-with-arcgis-pro.html) for details.

If there are folder permission issues mentioned above you can run PyScripter as an Administrator.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".