# Running ArcPy on PyScripter with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, installation, python-script-tool, pyscripter

Having `PyScripter 4.0.0.6 x64` installed with `ArcGIS Pro 2.5` I have set the

[image]

I have add/set the `arcgispro-py3-clone` to Python Path like below

[image]

but I am still getting this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 12, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcpy'
```

when trying to `import arcpy`

I also noticed that after re-opening the `Python Path` the order list of file path backed to default and not seeing the `arcgispro-py3-clone`

> C:\Users\somebody\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone

in the path list anymore!

[image]

What is happening here and how I can fix this?

Comment: Does this post help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277351/how-do-i-get-pyscripter-to-recognize-python-installed-with-arcgis-pro-2-1

Answer (score 1):

Click the Python icon (probably third from the right)
[image]

Click Add New Python Version
[image]

Navigate to and add your arcgispro-py3-clone folder.
Double click on the Conda under Unregistered Versions
[image]

Your PyScripter may look different but same process.